# Distance and hours between Phnom Penh and Tay Ninh

Tags: overland, vietnam, cambodia, phnom-penh, tay-ninh

How many kilometers from Phnom Penh to Tay Ninh if you travel by land?

How many hours is the trip from Phnom Penh to Tay Ninh by land?

Comment: Sorry user8300, we don't mean to scare you away from Stack Exchange, but there is an expectation that if you want answers that people put some effort into you should really put some effort into your question. Such as trying to find the answer before asking, and letting us know what you tried. Or if there's an obvious answer like Google, why it doesn't apply in your case. But I'm travelling in SE Asia right now too and I also would've just used Google Maps.

Comment: Dear user8300, google maps offer an easy way to do this, just pick locations and google maps will give you all kinds of details. Try it: https://maps.google.com.au/maps?saddr=Phnom+Penh,+Cambodia&daddr=Tay+Ninh,+Tay+Ninh+province,+Vietnam&hl=en&sll=11.558831,104.917445&sspn=0.279851,0.528374&geocode=Fa9fsAAdxelABinja2rHPVEJMTG7JbVa6A4BnA%3BFXZ0rQAdcEBTBinFPw256moLMTEV3whAIdFZoA&oq=tay+ninh&mra=ls&t=m&z=10

Answer (score 2):

Google Maps has a way of showing this for you.

In this case, [searching for directions between the two](https://www.google.com.au/maps/preview?saddr=Phnom%20Penh,%20Cambodia&daddr=Tay%20Ninh,%20Tay%20Ninh%20province,%20Vietnam&hl=en&sll=11.558831,104.917445&sspn=0.279851,0.528374&geocode=Fa9fsAAdxelABinja2rHPVEJMTG7JbVa6A4BnA;FXZ0rQAdcEBTBinFPw256moLMTEV3whAIdFZoA&oq=tay%20ninh&mra=ls&t=m&z=10) shows that it's approximately 179km-244km, depending on which highway/road you take.  The fastest route is expected to take 3 hours 20, and the longest will be just over 4 hours.

At this point you could look at the routes and perhaps check on google images for scenery; one route may be nicer to travel.  On the other hand if you're taking a taxi or public transport, you may not get that choice.